# Under what conditions does local concavity imply global concavity?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

I have the following result:

Assume $U:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is continuous and strictly increasing. Further, for every $a>0$ there exists a neighborhood (interval) $S$ of $a$ such that $U$ is concave on $S$.

Now I want to show that $U$ is concave on all of $\mathbb{R}^+$. I was thinking about using the fact that $U$ has a non-increasing right derivative on $int S$ (famous result by Stolz)- by continuity on $S$. However, I don't really know how to incorporate this.

Consider the following result: 
A function $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is concave if and only if for $x,y,z\in I, x<z<y$ it holds
$$\frac{f(x)-f(z)}{x-z} \geq \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \geq \frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}.$$

My intuition is the following. For any $x<z<y$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$ I know that around each of these points, $U$ is concave. Further, for any points in between $x,z,y$, the same situation holds. Hence, I use overlapping intervals, around the points in between, to show the above inequalities using Stolz result. However, I have the feeling that considered intervals need not necessarily overlap?!

What's your opinion on this?

Comment: This is similar to your proposed solution, but do you know that each concave function is (locally) absolutely continuous, where the (almost everywhere existent) derivative is nonincreasing (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, the result is true in any convex subset $D$ of a topological vector space: if $f: D \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and every $a \in D$ has a neighbourhood on which $f$ is concave then $f$ is concave on $D$.

Proof:  Suppose not.  Then there exist $a,b \in D$ and $t \in (0,1)$ such that
$f(t a + (1-t) b) < t f(a) + (1-t) f(b)$.  Define $g: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ by
$g(s) = f(sa + (1-s) b) - s f(a) - (1-s) f(b)$.  Then $g$ is continuous, and
every $s \in [0,1]$ has a neighbourhood on which $g$ is concave.  Note that 
$g(0) = g(1) = 0$ while $g(t) < 0$.  Let 
$y = \min\{g(s): s \in [0,1]\} < 0$, and $p = \max\{s: g(s) = y\} \in (0,1)$.
But $g(s) > g(p)$ on $(p,1]$ while $g(s) \ge g(p)$ on $[0,p)$, so there is no
neighbourhood of $p$ on which $g$ is concave.

Comment: +1 I am just not fluent enough in this stuff. I have to read it carefully and slowly, instead of instantly thinking "oh, yes". I guess the problem is I am not currently using it much ... No, that is a feeble excuse!

Comment: The reason that there is no neighborhood of p on which g is concave is that g(p) lies below the secant between any two points in the neighborhood of p?

Comment: Yes (for any two points where one is on one side and the other is on the other).

Answer (score 0):

Just a little addition to Robert Israel's great proof.

I had to think about why every $s\in[0,1]$ has a neighborhood on which $g$ is concave a little and came up with the following reasoning - for those who are interested.

Let $s\in[0,1]$ and consider the point $z(s):=s x + (1-s)y$. By assumption, $f$ is concave on an interval around $z(s)$ whose points can be described by convex combinations of $x$ and $y$. Hence, for $s_1,s_2$ around $s$ such that
$$z(s_1) = s_1 x + (1-s_1)y, \quad z(s_2) = s_2 x + (1-s_2)y$$ 
lie in the interval on which $f$ is concave, by midpoint concavity the following holds
\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{1}{2} z(s_1) + \frac{1}{2} z(s_2)\right) &\geq \frac{1}{2} f(z(s_1)) + \frac{1}{2} f(z(s_2))\\
\Leftrightarrow\quad\quad\,\,\, f\left(\frac{1}{2} z(s_1) + \frac{1}{2} z(s_2)\right)&\geq\frac{1}{2} f(s_1 x + (1-s_1)y) + \frac{1}{2} f(s_2 x + (1-s_2)y)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&\Leftrightarrow\quad f\left(\frac{1}{2} z(s_1) + \frac{1}{2} z(s_2)\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2}s_1 + \frac{1}{2}s_2\right) f(x) - \left(1-\frac{1}{2}s_1 - \frac{1}{2}s_2\right) f(y)\geq\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\frac{1}{2} f(s_1 x + (1-s_1)y) + \frac{1}{2} f(s_2 x + (1-s_2)y) - \left(\frac{1}{2}s_1 + \frac{1}{2}s_2\right) f(x) \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad - \left(1-\frac{1}{2}s_1 - \frac{1}{2}s_2\right) f(y)\\
&\Leftrightarrow\qquad\qquad\qquad\, g\left(\frac{s_1+s_2}{2}\right) \geq \frac{1}{2} g(s_1) + \frac{1}{2} g(s_2),
\end{align*}
since
$$f\left(\frac{1}{2} z(s_1) + \frac{1}{2} z(s_2)\right) = f\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}s_1 + \frac{1}{2}s_2\right)x + \left(1-\frac{1}{2}s_1 - \frac{1}{2}s_2\right) y\right).$$
Hence, for every $s\in[0,1]$  there exists a neighborhood on which $g$ is concave.